# Increase limit of bookmark folders in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

In Firefox 3, when you click the bookmark star to choose a Folder, you only get a list of the top 5 used folders. Is there a way to increase this limit to 10 or 15?, since I have lots of bookmark folders and use many frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in about:config and checked all options with the value of "5" and searched for "bookmarks" ect. No luck unfortunately. I don't think you are going to get something like this out of Firefox without some sort of add-on. [Searching around](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=x31&q=firefox+recent+bookmarks+addon&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) there are a few add-ons for bookmarks, but I don't know if they do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use "[Change Bookmark Recent Folder List Length](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/change-bookmark-recent-folder-)" Add On as some poster has already mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/857290)

Comment: Could you provide some more detail? Like a link?

Comment: @Scott my post contains a link! But ok, I added Add On's link

Comment: This addon seems to be not available anymore.