# How do I increase the available bookmark folder limits in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

As another user asked about firefox:
[Increase limit of bookmark folders in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/38325/increase-limit-of-bookmark-folders-in-firefox)

I would like to increase the number of folders that you are presented with when you press the add bookmark star in Chrome. As it is now, you get a choice from the last five used folders, "bookmark bar", "other bookmarks" or choose another folder. The last five folders are listed in a last in last out progression, so if you happen to bookmark five different pages to five different folders the sixth folder chosen would move the first one out.

It would also be a nice option if along with increasing the number of presented folders, to  pin chosen folders to always appear in the pulldown selection, regardless if I have used it recently or not, so if I find that I have bookmarked 10 different pages to their respective folders, that "my" most used folders are always quickly available.

A different solution would be to allow the creation of a(nother) special folder called "pinned favorites" that would be displayed along with "bookmarks bar" and "other bookmarks" that contain the folder selection that you choose to not be a part of the sequential deletion of the five "most recently used" folders. This folder would display the pinned folder selection once "pinned folders" was selected as a pulldown similar to the choose another folder option.

Comment: I doubt you’ll find a solution; unlike Firefox which lets you configure a lot of things, Google is still *trying* to keep Chrome minimal and basic which means forcing users to live with their (arbitrary and capricious) decisions instead of choosing for yourself.

Comment: And when you add a new bookmark to the folders most of the time you need to "choose other folders". I would like to be able to see all the folders from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is a"no" answer, per the comment to the question: this is not possible to modify.

Your best bet is to create a bug, or submit your own patch.

Answer (score 2):

The limit of 5 folders is [hardcoded](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/318345ccda37a7f187e6014baff53a2d4eb2bdab/chrome/browser/ui/bookmarks/recently_used_folders_combo_model.cc#L21-L22).

I've been [patching chromium](https://gist.github.com/gg7/8172378) for years because of this.

Comment: Thanks for conclusively answering this. Also I can confirm that the latest version of chromium as of August 2022 still has the same hardcoded limit: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/chrome/browser/ui/bookmarks/recently_used_folders_combo_model.cc#L23

Answer (score 0):

According to this forum https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/yQ3jbWf0DgU it has never been a feature to create a top level folder in bookmarks. I have noticed that connecting a chrome account on iOS has created a "Mobile Bookmarks" folder, but otherwise seems impossible to create or edit the top level folders.

Answer (score 0):

This chrome extension can implement the requested functionality.
https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/bookmark-plus/kcipcflegclplnkpbijedkhgljodgfcp?hl=en
[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Let me give it a shot: I f I understand you correctly, you want to have as many folders as you like in the chrome bookmarks?? If so, here we go:
- right-click on your chrome's "customise and control Google Chrome" icon bar and select "bookmarks" OR some other way to get to the BOOKMARK MANAGER.
- under any of the "bookmarks Bar" or "other bookmarks" ribbon item you can right-click to add / create as many folders as you want. this lets you organize your bookmarks. The Creation of these SUB folders will be visible on your chrome bar.