# Firefox: Is it possible to change the number of recently used bookmark folders?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Is it possible to increase the number of recently used folders when creating/editing a bookmark (yellow highlighted area) in Firefox ~34?

[image: Firefox: Bookmarks popup with folder dropdown]

I've tried

- searching the internet
- searching the configs (`about:config`) for "5", "bookmark", "places", ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy.  Install the **Change Bookmark Recent Folder List Length** Firefox extension.  It accomplishes *exactly* what you want.

You can get it [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/change-bookmark-recent-folder-).

Many times, when you need Firefox to do something special or different, you can search [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/) for an extension that will get the job done.  Firefox is known to be the most customizable web browser in the world.  Mozilla has unfortunately removed some important customizable items recently, but even with those changes, it is still more customizable than anything else.

Comment: Oh great! *Check* I havn't found that when searching Mozilla Addons. I made an audit of the plugin's v1.1.0 source code: it looks OK. (Basically the author has copied and modified the original Javascript and configured the Addon to override the builtin source.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to change the number of currently visible recently used folders since the count is hardcoded in the Firefox sourcecode:

Defined in **browser/components/places/content/editBookmarkOverlay.js, line 6:**

```
const MAX_FOLDER_ITEM_IN_MENU_LIST = 5;
```

Used in **browser/components/places/content/editBookmarkOverlay.js, line 323:**

```
var numberOfItems = Math.min(MAX_FOLDER_ITEM_IN_MENU_LIST,
                             this._recentFolders.length);
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
  this._appendFolderItemToMenupopup(menupopup,
                                    this._recentFolders[i].folderId);
}
```

Used source code: ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/34.0.5/source/firefox-34.0.5.source.tar.bz2